# Generated number sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me to generate number's sequence that repeat every **n** number **n** times. It would look like like this 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 ... It will be nice to get result without using temporary tables and loops.

For example I can get simple sequence from 1 to 1000 using this code

```
;WITH n(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n < 1000
)
SELECT n FROM n ORDER BY n
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

But how to reorganise code to get sequence described above?

Comment: The answer to this question changes a lot depending on the version -- is this 2012 or an early version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Hogan it will be fine to get result to the MSSQL 2008+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a sequence till 2048, you can use this code (you can easily modify it to get more numbers though):

```
DECLARE @N INT;
SET @N = 5;

WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT number + 1 number
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
)
SELECT A.number
FROM Numbers A
CROSS JOIN Numbers B
WHERE A.number >= B.number
AND A.number <= @N
ORDER BY A.number;
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/624) for you to try.

And the results are:

```
╔════════╗
║ number ║
╠════════╣
║      1 ║
║      2 ║
║      2 ║
║      3 ║
║      3 ║
║      3 ║
║      4 ║
║      4 ║
║      4 ║
║      4 ║
║      5 ║
║      5 ║
║      5 ║
║      5 ║
║      5 ║
╚════════╝
```

Comment: @Vsevywniy I edited my answer with a link to sqlfiddle with a demo of it and also the results that you get